# Can I replace my setup project with backed up version

Tags: vb.net, setup-project

I have some broken depencencies in a vb.net desktop app setup project and I have been unable to solve the problem. I wonder if I can do as follows:

- Remove the setup project from the solution and delete it in windows explorer
- Copy the setup project folder from my last backup of the solution files
- Add the backed up folder to my solution

Are there any pitfalls to this method so that I should rather create the setup project again from scratch?

Comment: I think this might work. You could also create a backup of your solution before you attempt such a thing.

Comment: I don't see why you'd need to even remove it from the solution.  The solution file just refers to each project file.  If you just delete the existing project folder and replace it with a backup, it should just work, as long as the project file and relative path is still the same.  Definitely backup the whole solution before doing so.  Also, start using source control so this becomes a non-issue.

Comment: It worked, thanks for comments. Point taken on source control.¨